# Capybara selector for a span within a

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, xpath, rspec, capybara

Hello I've been struggling with a should be simple select with capybara. This is what I'm after on my page :

```
<a title="Activity" class="" href="/changes">Activity <span class="badge">1</span></a>
```

I need to assert that there is a `span.badge` with value `1` inside activity `a` tag.

Before I posted this, printed the page contents and did a `save_and_open_page` and this content is there.

This is what I tried (which seemed most promising cant even find a tag) :

```
find(:xpath, "//a[contains(.,'Activity')]")
find(:xpath, "//a[contains(@title, \"Activity\")]")
find(:xpath, "//a[@title='Activity']")
find(:xpath, "//a", :text => /reActivity /i)
```

And so many other things not worth mentioning, how would you do this?

**Question update:**

I forgot to mention that this html is actually hidden initially on the page as it is part of a sub menu. So adding `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false` works but it kind of sux to add this global config to your test, any other ideas?

Comment: Why are you checking for hidden content?  Your test really should perform whatever action would make the content visible and then confirm it's on the page -- otherwise you're not really verifying anything that would make a difference to the user

Comment: @Tom Walpole because the menu is so big it needs to go under the submenu, and the activity badge should show only when certain data changes and the user access that part of the app, it's per design. I can't change app design for test purpose. It does make a difference to the user who is using that part of the app only

Comment: But there has to be something the user does to make it visible - which is what you should be doing and then testing the data is visible - anyway if you really have to test it when its not visible on the page you can add the visible: :all  or visible: :hidden option to the find depending on whether you don't care about visibility or only want to find non-visible

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do you can use a css selector for this, which will be easier to read than XPath

```
find('a[title=Activity] span.badge', text: '1', visible: :all)
```

Assuming the elements are visible on the page that should find what you want.  To assert on that if using RSpec something like the following with work

```
expect(page).to have_css('a[title=Activity] span.badge', text: '1', visible: :all)
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correctly

```
//a[@title="Activity" and span[@class="badge" and . = 1]]
```

Comment: thanks for the response, I just tried your suggestion `find(:xpath, '//a[@title="Activity" and span[@class="badge" and . = 1]]')` and this is the response `Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find xpath "//a[@title=\"Activity\" and span[@class=\"badge\" and . = 1]]"
from /Users/ned/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@sms/gems/capybara-2.3.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:41:in `block in find'`

Comment: http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath/?save=4e76b355-477a-4ff6-8db8-b8d20f59b52e-xpath Maybe i am wrong with structure of html?

Comment: this your xpath `find(:xpath, "//a[@title='Activity']")` should work too. It is problem not with the xpath.